# Difference between Floor Database and Sqlite Database

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, floor

Im on myproject app using flutter framework however i see this `Floor Database` that is quite similar if im right to `Sqlite Database` now im looking for there disadvage and advantage in development any one with the perfect explanation to there differences will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

According to the Floor documentation, it is a SQFlite abstraction.

Some advantages of Floor:

- Less boiler plate
- Light weight framework
- Reactive and type safe
- Allows for easy testing

Some disadvantages of Floor:

- Fairly new library (it might not be great for writing production code in)
- Lacks of a few features still

Some advantages of SQFlite:

- Feature rich
- Stable (Able to write production code with)

Some disadvantages of SQFlite:

- A lot of boiler plate code
- Does not have type safety off the bat

Hope that helps!